# Session value set in one file, can't read in other

Tags: php

I create a session-variable for passing error messages from my mail.php file to the file that called it.

```
session_start();
if(something) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "something went wrong";
}
```

I try to read it in the file that called mail.php:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['error'];
} else {
    echo "Email sent!";
}
```

But it's not working. I call session_start() at the top of the page at both files.

A var_dump gives this:

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> string(41) "Not all fields are filled in." } ­
```

Comment: Are you using `unset($_SESSION['error'])` somewhere in `mail.php`?

Comment: You have condition before setting session variable. Make sure it's true. In another words debug your code.

Comment: @PLB I can test it so it returns true, I've tried it.

Comment: Did you try debugging? Meaning, `var_dump( $_SESSION );` line by line after your `session_start` until you find out at what point the entry disappears.

Comment: @DainisAbols Just did it, amended question.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are only accessible when you reload the page.
In the same pageload it won't be accessible.
I ran into this isue too.
Depends maybe on the execution order or something.

Trying using the globals array as backup if the session variable isn't set.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['var'])) $x = $_GLOBALS['var'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`session_write_close();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) at the end of your session calls.